# CS1061: 'home_aspx' does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to make OnClick event from asp.net button but whenever I make the event it keeps giving me the error shown in the pictures below

It only happens when I make an event if I put the button without assigning an event to it, it won't give me the error.

Error I get:

[image]

HTML code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <form runat="server">
        <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Eve</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView_photos_home" runat="server">
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
                <td align="center">Eve</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center" style="margin-left: 40px">

                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_uploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload File" OnClick="Btn_uploadFile_click" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_isUpload" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

C# code "Code Behind":

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Final_Project_Bachelor
{
    public partial class Home1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Btn_uploadFile_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using an IDE (like Visual Studio) or trying to do this from text files?  On first look, it seems like the problem is your namespace.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017

Comment: OK, are you using the IDE to create the event?  Did you double-click on the button?  You should not be creating events by hand.

Comment: I did try double click on the button and create it manually though making method and on the button properties edit the Click event and it keep giving me same error

Comment: try starting over.  Don't create any event methods manually. Theoretically, you can do everything manually, but it's easy to mess it up.  The IDE handles all the details.

Comment: I tried that too, also I tried deleting the whole page and start over, rebuild the solution

Comment: still have the problem?

Comment: Start with a whole new solution.  Don't delete things.

Comment: Still have the problem, is there anyway to avoid making new solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229080/discussion-between-3bady-and-joelfan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for that. At the top of the HTML or Design page you'll find code line like this:

[image]

You need to change `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write **CodeBehind** and **Inherits** in path with the long method inside the tag at the top of the page on the frontend. I understand that the back-end and frontend relationship has not been established.